# In Firebase whats the difference between push and childByAutoId

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase if I'd like to create a child node with a unique ID it appears I have two options:

Push() :

> Use the push() method to append data to a list in multiuser
>   applications. The push() method generates a unique ID every time a new
>   child is added to the specified Firebase reference. By using these
>   auto-generated keys for each new element in the list, several clients
>   can add children to the same location at the same time without write
>   conflicts. The unique ID generated by push() is based on a timestamp,
>   so list items are automatically ordered chronologically.

childByAutoId:

> childByAutoId generates a new child location using a unique key and
>   returns a FIRDatabaseReference to it. This is useful when the children
>   of a Firebase Database location represent a list of items. The unique
>   key generated by childByAutoId: is prefixed with a client-generated
>   timestamp so that the resulting list will be chronologically-sorted.

Whats the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind, it appears they are the same except they cater to different platforms:

[Save Data on IOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data)

> `childByAutoId`   : Add to a list of data. Every time you call childByAutoId, Firebase generates a unique ID, such as `user-posts/<user-id>/<unique-post-id>`.

[Save Data on Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data)

> `push()`  : Add to a list of data. Every time you call `push()`, Firebase generates a unique ID, such as `user-posts/<user-id>/<unique-post-id>`.

Comment: `push` and `childByAutoId` are indeed the same logic with different names. When we tested with iOS developers they found `childByAutoId` to be more idiomatic. Btw: can you add links to the documentation where you got the snippets from? That will give others some more context.

Comment: Only push() is available in Flutter